# Moving pointers VS. Just iterating the string

Tags: java, algorithm, analysis

I am a beginner in preparing interview questions. I recently have a question about iterating a string.

When dealing with questions like ["Valid Palindrome"](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/description/) and similar questions, we usually have 2 ways to solve the question.

We either keep updating pointers until we find the target char:

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
int lo = 0;
int hi = s.length() - 1;
while(hi > lo){
    while(lo < hi && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(lo))) lo ++;
    while(hi > lo && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(hi))) hi --;

    if(s.charAt(lo) != s.charAt(hi)) return false;

    lo ++;
    hi --;
}

return true;
```

Or just iterating the string (from leetcode discussion):

```
int head = 0, tail = s.length() - 1;
char cHead, cTail;
while(head <= tail) {
    cHead = s.charAt(head);
    cTail = s.charAt(tail);
    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(cHead)) {
        head++;
    } else if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(cTail)) {
        tail--;
    } else {
        if (Character.toLowerCase(cHead) != Character.toLowerCase(cTail)) {
            return false;
        }
        head++;
        tail--;
    }
}

return true;
```

I am not sure which method is better in terms of big O analysis and which one to use during an interview?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't use "big-O analysis" as a synonym for "how efficient is it".  Both algorithms are proportional to the length of the string, so they're both `O(n)`.  One algorithm may be faster in each loop iteration, or it may greater or lesser fixed overhead, but those nuances are not part of big-O analysis.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. Just want to make sure that the time complexity in the first method is still O(n) even though there is a cascaded loop in the method?  Is that because of the internal loop is just updating pointers?

Answer (score 3):

The second is better.

- The first also treats `lo == hi` and
- repeats the condition of the outer loop.
- Also `charAt` is repeated for the same index. (Though in the second cTail might not have been gotten.)

The second is less complex, lazier, handling small cases, small steps, easily verifiable.

The second could be written in nicer style as:

```
//char cHead, cTail;
while(head <= tail) {
    char cHead = s.charAt(head);
    char cTail = s.charAt(tail);
```

As a declaration inside a loop is no overhead, just a single stack variable is reserved for a variable.